# No connection events are being fired - Mongoose 4.7.1 & Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having issues connecting my express app to MongoDB via Mongoose. There is no complicated set up, its fairly basic:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/homeApp');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("connecting", function(){
    console.log("Connecting to DB...");
});

db.on('connected', function(){
    console.log('Connected to db');
});

db.on('error', function(error){
    console.log('Error');
});
```

Simple enough, right? But none of these events are being fired. Mongo is running ok and it's on the default port. I have also tried changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and checked the contents of my `etc/hosts` file and all seems ok. If I mangle the URI string to something like:

```
'mongoldb://lclhost/homeApp'
```

I get an error saying it cannot connect, which is to be expected so it seems like a connection is being made/attempted but nothing is happening.

I've logged the contents of `db.Db` to the console and noticed this `connected: false`, which suggests it's not even attempting a connect?

Any ideas? This is Mongoose 4.7.1 running on macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it! I tried using the mongodb client without mongoose and everything worked as expected, so I knew the connection was ok and that left the blame with mongoose.

Turns out I was not using 4.7.1 as I had thought, and that just running `npm install mongoose --save` had in fact installed version 3.x, which is not compatible with the latest version of MongoDB according to the Mongoose docs. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html

Upgrading the version number in my `package.json` file to 4.7.1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the mongoose.connect method takes in a callback, which you could use to check the connection:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, options, function(error) {
  // Check error in initial connection.
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('connected ok');
  }
});
```

I think your connection is being created, but your db.on events are not being triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still nothing logging out. Interestingly I accidentally pasted your response below my existing connection call, and it complained that I was trying to open and unclosed connection, so clearly something is happening!